# two instance of socket with same port and address

Tags: java, android, sockets

i have a simple question when in make two sockets say: 
`Socket s1 = new Socket(ipAddress, 80);` 
`Socket s2 = new Socket(ipAddress, 80);`

when is bind the first one `s1` to httpclientConnection and 
the other one, `s2` was used was used internally (i think) for HttpUrlConnection
would i get the same metrics as `s2` when i get the metrics (HttpConnectionMetrics) of `s1`?

i just want to get the metrics of this second socket that was used by the third party lib.

Comment: both of these are going to connect to the same server side socket

Comment: What do you define as 'metric'? The code above will create **two separate connection** into the same server/port

Comment: as i said, the HttpConnectionMetrics instance. i will use that instance to get the sentBytesCounts of a socket. thanks guys.

Comment: @Mateusz That true for **ServerSocket**. You _can_ connect two (Client)Sockets to the same IP/Port. I think the OP was talking about "connecting to" rather than "binding".

Comment: There is no 'binding' here. There is just *connecting.* @Mateusz Your comment is hopelessly confused.

Comment: my bad. it was SocketHttpClientConnection. there's a bind method there.

Comment: Eh? The code you posted connects two `Sockets` with no binding at all (other than what happens by default behind the scenes, which isn't relevant anyway, but by the time these constructors return, both sockets are already bound, whatever you may think `SocketHttpClientConnection` is doing). You aren't making yourself clear here.

Comment: sorry, i was asking if i bind the socket s1 to SocketHttpClientConnection instance, would i get the same state as the state of the socket s2 ( which was used internally by third party lib).

Comment: I don't know what 'bind the socket to SocketHttpClientConnection' even means, but there isn't anything you can do do a socket that will confuse it with another one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Would I get the same metrics as s2 when i get the metrics (HttpConnectionMetrics) of s1?

No. What makes you think otherwise? Two sockets, two connections, two sets of metrics.

Comment: yeah., just asking.. because they were trying to connect with the same host. thanks. sorry for the dump question.